# Node.js redirect to another node.js file

Tags: node.js, express

I want to do a re-direction from one nodejs file to another nodejs file. I used res.redirect(URL), but when execute it says "cannot GET /nodepage"

Currently I am using

```
// Handler for GET /
app.get('/nodepostgres', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/nodepost.js?a=1');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think there are a few things that you don't explain properly or don't understand properly in your question.

I am not sure what you mean about "re-direction from one nodejs file to another nodejs file". You seems to think that a node script file correspond to a URL (or a page). That's wrong. A node script correspond to an application that may (or may not) expose several pages through several URL and can imports application logic from other script files (you will run a single root script file for a site or application). It's totally different from what you may know with (vannilla, no framework) PHP.

Exposing different pages through different url is called Routing, all Express documentation about routing can be [found here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing).

What I understand is that your trying to make a function / page / Url per script : nodepost.js file is a page. Code organization is a good thing but let's focus on how node + express works first.

From what I understand, you're applicaton has a few exposed url, let's say :

- "/" homepage
- "/nodepostgre" (maybe accepting an 'a' arg ?)
- "/nodepost" accepting an arg : a

Note : we forget the id of file = page, we don't want an extension to appear on URL so `nodepost.js` becomes `nodepost`

What you can do is setup the 3 url expositions :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) { res.render('home'); }); // render the home page
app.get('/nodepost', function(req, res) { // expose the nodepost function
  var a = req.params.a;
  doSomethingWith(a);
  // res.render, res.send ? whatever you want...
]);
app.get('/nodepostgres', function(req, res){ // use of res.redirect(url[, status])
  res.redirect('/nodepost');
});
```

Is that what you want ?

Then, here is a more elegant way to handle params ("a").

```
app.get('/notepost/:a', function(req, res) { // called via /nodepost/here_goes_a_valu ; no "?"
  var a = req.params.a;
```

});

Why is it better ?

1. Respect [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) (may not be the best link to describe rest but...)
2. Allows you to expose '/nodepost' without params
3. Certainly one million other things